# How dominant is LaTeX in academics & publishing?

Tags: msword, journal-publishing, adobe, publishing

Are there any public stats that demonstrate how much literature is produced in LaTeX as opposed to Microsoft Word, Adobe InDesign, etc? When I search "latex market share" every single result talks about rubber/pillow/mattress companies and not the typesetter.

From what I have heard LaTeX is heavily used in Math & Science theses, and I would like to find specific numbers to back that claim. Does LaTeX stand a chance against other software outside the Natural Sciences, its stronghold?

Comment: See the end of https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb44-1/tb136beet.pdf for a _very_ brief discussion of this.

Comment: For searching, the key is to add or remove keywords, e.g. like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22latex+share%22+typesetting, to learn from the results and to further modify the search terms. // E.g. if you even add statistics to said search term, you'll find e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29236/statistics-about-latex-use-in-the-world, which gives you an idea. // Or add trend instead of statistics. <end of primer on basic search>

Comment: Fortunately, market share is really a secondary issue for  free software. The popularity of a free sotware with respect commercial alternatives is indicative of nothing.  The only valid fact  is if *for you* is better that any other option.